# Asymptotic expansion for sum involving divisor function

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Could someone tell me if there is a more precise asymptotic expansion for this sum?

$$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{d(n)}{n}=\frac{1}{2} \ln^{2}x+2\gamma \ln x+c+O(x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\ln x) $$
$$d(n)=\sum_{a|n}1$$

Comment: this is answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/471326/87355